# Does Windows 10 Pro for Workstations include Microsoft Bloatware or allow removal with group policy?

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

Does Windows 10 Pro for Workstations include Microsoft Bloatware or [allow removal with group policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51837.windows-10-how-to-turn-off-microsoft-consumer-experiences.aspx) like the enterprise version allows for or it is like regular pro which does not allow this?

Comment: The text you refer to (Educational or Enterprise) is way down the window where you change the setting. However, I do not see any issue, performance loss, or productivity loss in the default setting.

Comment: With the default setting Windows will install extra apps by default (like random games).  My goal is to make my install be like the LTSB version but legally obtain it and was hoping Pro for Workstations could do this.

Comment: Please read more about what LTSB actually is before using that term. LTSB is not analogous to Ubuntu's long term support builds or the full OS clean of what you call "bloatware". It is a limited function version of Windows intended for limited function devices such as Kiosks and embedded controllers.

Comment: @EricJohnson - The limitation of Windows 10 Professional and Windows 10 Professional for Workstations is identical when it comes to group policies.  Worth pointing out it is trivial to create an installation of Windows 10 that does not include those default applications.